# Download file with Angular

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I am writing a small music blog with Django for the back-end and Angular for the front-end but I'm currently stuck. In my blog's detail page, I've succeeded in showing in displaying the music information.

Now my problem is to add a button that download the music file when clicked.
When I log the information returned from `details.component.ts`, I get the following:

```js
{id: 1, artist: 'Artist_name', title: 'The_music_title', thumbnail: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image_file.png', audio_file: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/name_of_music_file.mp3', …}
```

I can't use the code below because the file audio file is cross-origin. Whenever I click on the button, it only opens a new tab and start playing the song there

```html
<a href="{{data.audio_file}}" download="{{data.title}}">
    <button type="button">Download</button>
</a>
```

**EDIT:**
I added a new url that accepts a music id, queries the database for a music object with that id and downloads the song.
So when tried visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/download/1`, it downloaded the song

Comment: By "I can't use the code below because the file audio file is cross-origin", you mean that the call to django backend returns in a cross-origin error?. Do you have a possibility to configure django-backend's allowed origins to have your frontend url (like http://localhost:4200)?

Comment: I've edited the the question

Comment: Don't nest a button inside a a-tag. If it is a link, use an a tag. If it is a button use a button tag. It's never both tags at the same time!

Comment: Thanks! I did ```<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/download/{{data.id}}/" download="{{data.title}}">Download</a>``` and it worked. But is there a way I can avoid hard-coding the url

Answer (score 0):

for hardcoding url I think you can declare a variable in ts and concatinate it with data.id

```
{{url + data.id}}
```

```
url: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/download/';
```